# Contar de un rango a otro dentro de una tabla en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, concat, sum

Muy buenas a todos, si alguien pudiera ayudarme con el siguiente problema por favor.
Esto realizando un sistema de personal y en mi tabla vacaciones almaceno el id fecha de salida y la fecha de retorno, de una tabla calendario donde se quito el domingo, y quiero hacer el conteo de ambos campos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

total 14 registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

utilizo resta pero entre 157-170 = 13 lo cual no es la funcion que necesito y si el solo el mismo dato tiene que ser 1.
muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola. Dices que almacenas tienes tres campos en la tabla: id, fecha salida y fecha retorno. Pero luego, en la imagen, aparece un id, una fecha y un día de la semana. No se corresponde con lo que dices. Tampoco me queda claro lo que quieres. ¿"Hacer el conteo de ambos campos" o contar las filas (vamos, saber cuántos días se está de vacaciones, sin contar los domingos)? Por favor, muestra la sentencia SQL que estás utilizando.

Comment: Lo correcto seria utilizar [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html), pero necesitaríamos ver tu consulta para darte una respuesta. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la consulta SQL que estas realizando?

Comment: Bienvenido River a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres contar? ¿La cantidad de días hábiles? ¿los totales?

Answer (score 0):

Cuándo quieres saber cuántos números hay en un rango que incluye los extremos, debes sumar uno al rango.

```
N = LimiteSuperior - LimiteInferior + 1
```

Por ejemplo, para saber cuántos números hay del 7 al 7 (incluidos los extremos), la fórmula es:

```
N = 7 - 7 + 1
N = 1
```

Del 7 al 7, hay 1 número.

Para saber cuántos números hay del 1 al 4, extremos incluidos, la fórmula es:

```
N = 4 - 1 + 1
N = 4
```

Por esta misma razón, dado que los Id's son consecutivos, te falta sumar uno al resultado.

Así:

```
NumeroDias = idFechaFin - idFechaIni + 1
```

```
NumeroDias = 170 - 157 + 1 = 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente unos genios realmente logre solucionarlo muchas gracias. quedo así.

```
SELECT 

id_vacaciones,

fecha_solicitud,

solicitante,

motivo_vacacion,

desde,

hasta,

(hasta - desde)+1 AS total1,

idusuario

FROM personal_vacaciones
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]